# Rewrite not working

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I am absolutely lost, trying anything silly. Probably you know the situation. I tried hints from many threads here and on Google as well, but nothing helped. I have rewrite module loaded on my Apache (checked by phpinfo). For a site I have .htaccess created, where currently simple rule is stored:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/certifikaty\.html$ certifikaty.php
```

So, I expect http://www.contech.cz/certifikaty.html will show http://www.contech.cz/certifikaty.php. Unfortunatly not. So, I set in my httpd.conf these lines:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log"
```

The file (rewrite.log) is created, but it's empty even after server restart.

Please, could you help me to get out of this?

Marek

Comment: Remove the `/`. `RewriteRule` does not include the beginning `/` of the request URI.  `RewriteRule ^certifikaty\.html$ certifikaty.php [L]`

Comment: sure, it was one of my trials ..... it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Do you expect it to _redirect_ to `certifikaty.php` or internally rewrite?  If you need a redirect add `[L,R=301]`

Comment: I am expecting output of certifikaty.php in my web browser. Instead of that, I am getting 404. Adding [L,R=301] didn't help :(.

Comment: Does the file `/certifikaty.php` actually exist?  Which of them is the _real_ file?

Comment: LOL, but I understand ... yes, http://www.contech.cz/certifikaty.php works fine, http://www.contech.cz/certifikaty.html gives me 404. The PHP file is the real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - I had directive AllowOveride None in my httpd.conf. It means all httpd.conf are ignored ....